# How to find whole complete number with ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking to find the first whole occurance of a number within a string. I'm not looking for the first digit, rather the whole first number. So, for example, the first number in: **w134fklj342** is 134, while the first number in **1235alkj9342klja9034** is 1235.

I have attempted to use \d but I'm unsure how to expand that to include multiple digits (without specifying how long the number is).

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev is correct. But you should read [Regexp docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) to learn more on what the Regexp provides.

Answer (score 5):

I think, you're looking for this regex

```
\d+
```

"Plus" means "one or more". This regex will match all numbers within a string, so pick first one.

```
strings = ['w134fklj342', '1235alkj9342klja9034']

strings.each do |s|
  puts s[/\d+/]
end
# >> 134
# >> 1235
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/YE8kPE2SyW

Comment: Correct, but more simply just: s[/\d+/]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to understand regexes is to think of eachbit is one character; e.g: `\d` or `[1234567890]` or `[0-9]` will match one digit.

To expand this one character you have 2 basic options: `*` and `+`

- `*` will match the character 0 or more times
- `+` will match it one or more times

Like Sergio said you should use `\d+` to match many digits.

Excellent tutorial for regexes in general: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html